# Can I create a stacked bar chart using a pandas dataframe with incomplete x-values and map custom x-tick labels?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

In a nutshell, I have a pandas dataframe with data from multiple numbers in a range of, say, 3000-3010. At some of these points, there is data in the dataframe. Say, position 3001 has a value of 1, 3003 has a value of 4, 3007 has a value of 10, but there is no data for any of the other positions. I would like to create a stacked bar chart that ranges over the entire range of 3000-3050. I would also like to map custom x-tick labels (it's a genomic sequence, so some combination of ACTG) to the x-axis. My initial idea is to quickly populate the dataframe for all locations that don't currently exist within the dataframe and give them values of 1. Is there any easier way than this to create the desired graph, or is there an easy way to quickly populate a dataframe in a range of position values with 0? I am not experienced with pandas and am struggling to find an answer!

I've written a table of the example below and what I would like it to actually look like (for my approach to the problem) to allow me to cleanly graph it.

Edit: There should be a value1 and value2 to make the stacked bar chart of the question valid.

| Position | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 3001 | 1 |
| 3003 | 4 |
| 3007 | 10 |

| Position | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 3000 | 0 |
| 3001 | 1 |
| 3002 | 0 |
| 3003 | 4 |
| 3004 | 0 |
| 3005 | 0 |
| 3006 | 0 |
| 3007 | 10 |
| 3008 | 0 |
| 3009 | 0 |
| 3010 | 0 |

Comment: Maybe [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html). Possibly with a `fill_value` of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.reindex()`, assuming that `Position` is the DataFrame's index:

```py
df = df.reindex(index=list(range(3000, 3051)), fill_value=0)
```